# How can i disable fade effect on this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, fade

I am really new on javascript and maybe somebody with more experience can tell me
how can i disable fade effect in this function ?

(function(){

```
var textToChange = [
    'TEXT TO CHANGE',
    'TEXT TO CHANGE',
    ], i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $('#textToChange').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).html(textToChange[i=(i+1)%textToChange.length]).fadeIn();
    });
}, 2500);
```

})();

Comment: Remove the fade function

Comment: i just want that change the text without any effect... could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
function WhateverName(){

   var textToChange = ['TEXT TO CHANGE', 'TEXT TO CHANGE'], i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
       $('#textToChange').html(textToChange[i=(i+1)%textToChange.length]);
    }, 2500);
});
```

**Explanation**: Remove the fadeout function wrapped around the code and `fadein` function after your html function. Also, before you were using `this` which contained the instance of `'#textToChange'`. Since we removed the function wrapped around. `this` will no longer have the instance of required id element. Hence, we used `'#textToChange'` in next line to append html.

Check updated code..Also don't copy paste code...try to understand why it's not working...the actual basics of it...and check your console in browser..

Comment: Check updated code..Also don't copy paste code...try to understand why it's not working...the actual basics of it...and check your console in browser..